# I want to hide debug information in UWP

Tags: debugging, uwp

When debugging in **UWP**, **debugging information** like the red square box shown below is displayed.
How can I hide this?

[image]

Comment: It is shown in Debug mode only, in Release these boxes are not visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called **Frame Rate Counter**. This is showing because you're on debug mode. To remove this on debug mode, you need to go to `App.xaml.cs` and go to `OnLaunched()` event.

[image]

Change this:

```
this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```

to this:

```
this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = false;
```

It should remove the Frame counter.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It is well. Thank you

Comment: Good to know. You can upvote this answer if it helps, so it can also help other developers. Thanks! :)

Comment: I want to upvote but I do not have enough reputation points. i have just 10 point.